# Doesn't Joule's Law of heating suggest that all the potential energy supplied is converted to heat in a resistor

Tags: electric-current, work

I know it is a repeated question, but the other questions couldn't clear my doubts. So, sorry.

In the Joule's Law of heating, we say $P=VI$ where *V* is the potential difference across the resistor and *I* the current through the resistor. In a simple circuit with one resistor and a battery, *V* is equal to the potential difference supplied by the battery. So now when we plug in the values of *V* and *I*, doesn't it mean that all of the potential energy is lost as heat. But if that is the case then how do they get to the other side of the circuit, since all energy was just lost as heat.

Another question is that, isn't it actually the kinetic energy of the electron that is lost and not the potential energy of electron.

Or is the reason for why we say its potential energy that is lost as follows: When electron loses its kinetic energy as heat that much energy leaves the system. So it is equivalent of saying that that much potential energy of the system was lost even before the electron has entered the resistor.

Please consider criticising my explanation too.
Thank you

Comment: Ohms law I=V/R is that what you mean with plugging in the values?

Comment: Yes, that is it @Emil

Answer (score 1):

> But if that is the case then how do they get to the other side of the
>   circuit, since all energy was just lost as heat.

The two are not incompatible.  Imagine sliding a mass down a slope, and we have selected it so that the force of gravity and friction balance exactly.  Since there is no net force, the block does not accelerate.  The PE it loses by dropping down the slope goes into heat (friction losses).

The same thing happens here.  Without resistance, the charge would be accelerated from the high potential point to the low potential point.  But because of the resistor, the energy is converted into heat instead of KE.

When the circuit was first closed, there was a short time when some of the energy went into accelerating the charges to the steady-state current.  But after that time the energy only went into heating.

> Another question is that, isn't it actually the kinetic energy of the
>   electron that is lost and not the potential energy of electron.

No, because the KE isn't changing.  Again, think of the block sliding down the slope at constant speed.  The net work done on the mass is zero, so no change in KE.  In the circuit, the change in potential and the resistance losses sum to zero, so no change in KE.

> So it is equivalent of saying that that much potential energy of the
>   system was lost even before the electron has entered the resistor.

It's not lost before the resistor, it's lost in the resistor.  The change in PE is exactly balanced by the resistance losses.  If it weren't, the charges in that section would speed up until the losses balanced.

Comment: 1.Yeah, so you mean that all of the potential energy was converted to heat, right? 2. But even in the block example isn't potential actually converted to kinetic energy energy first and then isn't this kinetic energy which is converted to heat? 3.By "So it is equivalent of saying that that much potential energy of the system was lost even before the electron has entered the resistor." I didn't actually mean it was lost. I asked whether it was considered that way. THANK YOU

Comment: If the block isn't accelerating, then you can't really say that anything is being converted to KE.    If the wire has minimal resistance (close enough to zero for us to ignore), then we don't say any PE is lost there.  The PE is lost only as it goes through the resistor.  I was disagreeing with the word "before".

Comment: How is that possible, if  there were no resistance then electron would surely accelerate, right? Also please answer my other questions in the comment

Comment: Acceleration requires a net force.  Outside the resistor, the electric field is zero and there's no change in PE, therefore no change in KE either.   I'm not sure what I didn't address.  You might want to either ask it as a separate question or edit it into your original question.

Comment: I meant I didn't understand what you were concluding in the 1st question, are you saying that all of the potential energy is converted to heat? How is electric field outside resistor zero when it is connected to a battery?

Comment: Yes, unless the energy does work (like pushing a weight or something), then it will all be converted to heat.  The electric field inside a perfect conductor (at steady state) is zero.  Doesn't matter if there's a battery connected or not.

Comment: If field is zero then how does the  charges move in the first place? I think electrostatic equilibrium refers to conductors in external fields not when connected to a battery

Comment: Motion doesn't require force, acceleration requires force.  There is a changing field for a moment as the current is established.  Once the current is steady-state, the field is effectively zero in the wire.